# get sql for three tables with group by

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working in MS Access and need an SQL solution. I have three tables as:

1. Customers: *CustNum* (key), *Name*
2. Orders: *ID*, *CustNum*, *Amount*
3. Payments: *ID*, *CustNum*, *Value*

My problem is to write an SQL that would result into a query as:

*CustomerName, TotalOderValue, TotalAmountPaid, BalancePayable*.

I tried the below `Select` query on the three tables grouping by *CustNum* and it worked but seemed to balloon the summations probably due to repeating rows.

```
SELECT CustNum, 
       Sum(Amount) AS TotalOrderValue, 
       Sum(Value) AS TotalAmountPaid, 
       [TotalOrderValue]-[TotalAmoutPaid] AS BalancePayable  
FROM (Customers Inner Join Payments ON Customers.CustNum=Payments.CustNum) 
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustNum=Orders.CustNum GROUP BY Customers.CustNum
```

Comment: so you're hiring for a sql writer for your homework?

Comment: Can you please show us some code that you have written?

Comment: Added, please check and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic Access functionality.

Build 2 aggregate queries. Then build another query that joins those to the Customers table.

Or can nest the 2 aggregate queries within the third if you want. Use SQL View to copy/paste the 2 aggregate queries into the third query then can delete the 2 aggregate query objects. Here is the all-in-one query:

```
SELECT Customers.CustNum, Query1.TotalAmountPaid, Query2.TotalOrderValue, [TotalAmountPaid]-[TotalOrderValue] AS BalancePayable
FROM 
(SELECT Payments.CustNum, Sum(Payments.Value) AS TotalOrderValue FROM Payments GROUP BY Payments.CustNum) AS Query2 
RIGHT JOIN (
(SELECT Orders.CustNum, Sum(Orders.Amount) AS TotalAmountPaid FROM Orders GROUP BY Orders.CustNum) AS Query1 
RIGHT JOIN Customers ON Query1.CustNum = Customers.CustNum) ON Query2.CustNum = Customers.CustNum;
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! thanks so much for this, u just gave me rest after a week of struggle.